# strange behaviour with "rin" in brand new installation of 4.6.1

Tags: iis, windows

I am used to install WordPress by myself manually so I can control everything.

I basically grab the latest:

- PHP (5.6 NTS x64)
- MySQL Community Server
- WordPress (4.6.1)

Done it hundreads of times before, but this time around I am getting very awkward behaviour, e.g.

- I see the word "rin" rendered on every page
- the media library never finishes loading
- cannot upload files to media library, getting "rin" every time

Specs:

- Windows 10 Enterprise v1607
- WordPress 4.6 / 4.6.1
- IIS / FastCGI
- PHP 5.6 non thread safe x64

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

very first screen of a brand new database/wordpress setup
[image]

Comment: Disable all plugins and pick a default WordPress theme (twentysixteen). Then re-enable plugins and themes one by one to find out where this comes from.

Comment: its a brand new installation! as in, all I did was download and install the latest version from wordpress. no plugins, no themes, nothing. just plain old 2014 or 2015 or 2016. happens with all of them

Comment: In your screenshots I can see "Google Drive", that's not stock WordPress.

Comment: ^ I can confirm that this plugin has no bearing in the errors. it was actually installed after detecting the issues, I just took screenshots with it there. I have removed it now but I can ensure I've made several clean installs and the issue arrises actually in the first ever screen where wordpress asks for language

Comment: Apart from the "rin" thing the screenshot of your code also shows link, meta and title tags inside the body tag. That looks like something went seriously wrong during install. Given that it's fresh anyway, I'd try a completely new install.

Comment: @cjbj I had done nothing else than delete everything and reinstall everything over and over again. the very first screen for the language selctor already has the rin word there

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But have your tried another fresh install? It may have been a glitch during installation (hard disk error, whatever), leading your WP install to be corrupt without you having done anything wrong.

Comment: in the past 10 minutes I did 3 fresh installs! :)

Comment: this will be impossible to answer without access to your server. I am guessing your theme's functions.php file is corrupted, but that is a pure guess. you need to delete all files, re-download from wordpress.org a fresh copy and install it. If it is still happen, search your files where does it come from and then you can try to figure out why

Comment: I cannot say this any more clearer. I am downloading a fresh wordpress 4.6.1 from worpress.org. I am creating a new database, pasting the files and opening the site in iis. there is ZERO custom stuff

Comment: most of my biggest time wasters is when I think I am doing something, but I am actually doing something else. Either your copy of wordpress is corrupted or you HDD is corrupted in some very strange way.

Comment: I hear you. but I really have tried downloading multiple times multiple versions. I have a brand new laptop with an SSD drive and it would be the first time I experienced issues. I have tried to lookup for permissions issues, downloaded again, nothing works. I don't think it's hardware, it's most likely software. possibly problems with FastCGI or whatever. I'm amazed I am the apparently the only one in the whole world getting this

Comment: look like I found it... oh well

Answer (score 1):

the answer is too sad to be true so I'll just post a copy of my wp-config.php instead

```
rin<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
```

Comment: :( ok, should have suggested you fully delete the current directory as well ;)

Comment: actually one of your comments got me thinking, "am I actually doing something custom, I mean ANYTHING?", especially while I was answering "I have ZERO custom stuff" so yeah thanks

Comment: This has happened to me few times, usually it's *s*, instead of *rin*, when trying to save a file with *ctrl+s*  but missing out *ctrl* ;-)